# SlidesJS plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the Slidesjs plugin to create a slideshow on my website, but it is not working for some reason.

```
    <!--Javascript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/java" src="jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

  <script src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528
          });
        });
  </script>

<!--Javascript-->

<div id="slides">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                  </div>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the right jQuery library and why do you have 2 of them?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<!--Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 528
      });
    });
</script>

<!--Javascript-->

<div id="slides">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
              </div>
```

Or:

```
<!--Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.slides.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#slides").slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 528
      });
    });
</script>

<!--Javascript-->

<div id="slides">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
              </div>
```

Or even use the latest script library that you can, so that in future you can do more

Use Developer tools in firefox (I prefer that one but you can use another) to see what is conflicting in the scripts, it really would help you to become comfortable with something like that